# Confusion regarding reference of object

Tags: c++, object, reference, runtime-error

I was solving linked-list questions on hackerrank. The question was simple : Insert a node at the head of the linked-list. I only had to implement the function to insert the node at the head of the linked list. The linked-list class and other necessary functions were already defined. Here is the already given code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>


using namespace std;

class SinglyLinkedListNode {
  public:
    int data;
  SinglyLinkedListNode * next;

  SinglyLinkedListNode(int node_data) {
    this - > data = node_data;
    this - > next = nullptr;
  }
};

class SinglyLinkedList {
  public:
    SinglyLinkedListNode * head;
  SinglyLinkedListNode * tail;

  SinglyLinkedList() {
    this - > head = nullptr;
    this - > tail = nullptr;
  }

};

void print_singly_linked_list(SinglyLinkedListNode * node, string sep, ofstream & fout) {
  while (node) {
    fout << node - > data;

    node = node - > next;

    if (node) {
      fout << sep;
    }
  }
}

void free_singly_linked_list(SinglyLinkedListNode * node) {
  while (node) {
    SinglyLinkedListNode * temp = node;
    node = node - > next;

    free(temp);
  }
}

// Complete the insertNodeAtHead function below.

/*
 * For your reference:
 *
 * SinglyLinkedListNode {
 *     int data;
 *     SinglyLinkedListNode* next;
 * };
 *
 */
SinglyLinkedListNode * insertNodeAtHead(SinglyLinkedListNode * head, int data) {


}
```

---

I have two implementations of this function:
First...

```
SinglyLinkedListNode * insertNodeAtHead(SinglyLinkedListNode * head, int data) {

  SinglyLinkedListNode node(data);

  node.next = head;
  head = &node;

  return head;
}
```

Second....

```
SinglyLinkedListNode * insertNodeAtHead(SinglyLinkedListNode * head, int data) {

  SinglyLinkedListNode * ptr = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);

  ptr - > next = head;
  head = ptr;

  return head;
}
```

Second one works but first one gives runtime error.What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you are assigning the address of a local variable to `head`. As soon as the function returns, this variable goes out of scope, and `head` is pointing to an invalid object.

Comment: In the second example also , isn't ptr also a local variable?

Comment: Yes, but only the *value* of `ptr` is being used. If you take the *address* of `ptr`, you'd have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The first one creates a `SinglyLinkedListNode` with automatic [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), meaning that the object becomes invalid as soon as `insertNodeAtHead` returns. In practice, the object was likely allocated on the stack.

The second uses dynamic storage duration, meaning that it remains valid until you deallocate it using `delete`.